# Is it good practice to override simple db_query or EntityFieldQuery with a View

Tags: views, entities, ajax

I am using several autocomplete fields in a form. To retrieve the data, I have used `db_query` for very simple queries, `EntityFieldQuery` for more complex, until I found one that is somehow convoluted, so I used a **View** and `views_get_view_result` to retrieve the list of suggested terms. Is it a good practice or am I consuming too many resources instead of digging a little more in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer possible to this question because it very much depends on circumstances. The customary response to such fears is to invoke the spectre of [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and to advise you not to worry until you **know** you have a performance issue.

However, from an educational perspective it's probably worth at least looking at the query Views is executing and considering whether it is efficient: is it scanning every row of a large table because of the lack of an index, for example.

On the Views settings page there's an option to display the SQL for a query. You can copy and paste it into a tool such as PhpMyAdmin (removing the curly brackets peculiar to Drupal SQL queries) then put "EXPLAIN" in front of it to see what's happening under the hood.

But in general I would not bother to rewrite a query like this until there's a proven need to do so.

Comment: This whole answer should be in bold, flashing, red text with a "DO NOT PROCEED UNTIL YOU'VE READ AND UNDERSTOOD THIS" label at the top :)

Comment: I don't understand the reply. I am using SQL output and I have put it in my code - I can modify it to make it perform faster (if I know that all nodes are published, don't  even need to left join the node table). However, my question is if I could take confidence on the Views output. As I see it, if I hard code the db_query I am at risk of upgrades of the database layout affecting my query. If I use EntityFieldQuery I am more secure, but it is complicated. If I directly throw the output of the View, I have no worry anymore, not about obsolescence or my bad coding using EntityFieldQuery.

Comment: Your question asked about "consuming too many resources", so that's what I tried to address: how to know whether the SQL generated by a view is efficient or not. As I say, generally it's not something to worry about: go ahead and use the view until in realistic testing you find there's a performance issue.

Comment: Well, I am using the SQL query because I found problems to pass parameters to the view. So sad, so real. I hope that the SQL keeps working after upgrading modules and core.